# Jenkins Build number reset fails

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

So I am trying to reset the Jenkins build number on a job (as I have many time before) using this groovy code in the script console like so:

```
item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("your-job-name-here")
//THIS WILL REMOVE ALL BUILD HISTORY
item.builds.each() { build ->
  build.delete()
}
item.updateNextBuildNumber(1)
```

For some reason this no longer works so I tried installing the "Set next build number" plugin and this also doesn't have any effect.

I then tried changing the "nextBuildNumber" file relating to the job and asked Jenkins to reload config from disk.

Any ideas why the build number reset is proving to be such a challenge on Jenkins 2.46.3?

Comment: IIRC `Jenkins.instance.save()` or similar

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command in to delete all the existing builds and reset the build number to `1`.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def jobName = "NAME_OF_YOUR_JOB"
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)

job.getBuilds().each { it.delete() }
//reset the build number to 1:
job.nextBuildNumber = 1
job.save()
```

Comment: I gave that a try as well but still the build number is not set at one. I even tried clearing out the builds and artifacts from Artifactory.

Comment: I have tested in 2.60 and it's working. I am not sure if 2.46.3 has got any issue.